# how to set the fetch size when using quarkus reactive pg client

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, reactive, quarkus

I would like to control the [fetch size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#i1023619) in querying the Postgres DB.
I am able to do so with the plain jdbc, but with the [quarkus reactive postgres client](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients), I cannot find such an option. Anyone knows how to configure fetch size with this client?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible. If you use the normal query methods, vertx-sql-client will always fetch everything.

You can use [`PreparedStatement.createStream()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/sqlclient/PreparedStatement.html#createStream-int-io.vertx.sqlclient.Tuple-) instead if you want to stream the partial results.